# How to get length value from output stream to input stream in socket programming?

Tags: android, socket.io, inputstream, outputstream, wifi-direct

I am sending data using socket programming like this:

```
private class SendReceive extends Thread{
        private final Socket socket;
        private InputStream inputStream;
        private OutputStream outputStream;

        public SendReceive(Socket skt){
            socket = skt;
            try {
                inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4*1024*1024];
            int length;

            while (socket != null){
                try {
                    length = inputStream.read(buffer,0, buffer.length);
                    if (length>0){
                        handler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ,length,-1,buffer).sendToTarget();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public void write(byte[] bytes){
            try {
                Log.d("Data Length", ""+bytes.length);
                outputStream.write(bytes,0,bytes.length);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to get the `bytes.length` value from write while reading in inputstream as I'm not getting all values at a time. So I need to get the length value and want to also add all values until the receive length is the same as the output length.

Comment: `int bytes;` AND `byte[] bytes`. Very confusing! Please name the first `nread` or `nbytesread` or such.

Comment: What has write to do with read? The write goes to the server. And the read comes from the server. The server will send different amount of data then the client sent. Or... What is happening exactly? And did you program the server?

Comment: Actually, this is an application for wifi direct in this case connected devices are creating a group, and who is taking the group owner access I am treating it as a server and the server is reading snapshots sent by the client. So server is working with the run method and client using the write method.

Comment: When client is doing "outputStream.write(bytes,0,bytes.length);" in server side I want to get the "bytes.length" part in inputstream.

Comment: That is not the way such a problem is usually solved. Normally the sender would first send four bytes (an integer) indicating the amount of bytes that will be send. The receiver first reads that integer and then knows exactly how many bytes will follow.

Comment: Ok, I got your point. Yes, it can be a solution.